# How do you make a grid of vertices with design based on their degree?

Tags: graphics

I'm working on a graph theory problem, and need to map out a grid of nodes/vertices that denote their degree, and illustrates their paths. The graph I need is basically a 7 x 7 grid, that shows the amount of moves a knight on a chessboard would have if they occupied a location. I would like the color to darken as the degree increases.

The grid I need is identical to the blue 7 by 7 image in the third answer on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389945/use-the-handshake-lemma-to-determine-the-number-of-edges-in-gk-n), or shown below.

[image: 7x7 map]

I've tried modifying a bunch of examples I've found online, but I cannot create something quite like this.

Answer (score 3):

Here I use TeX counters to do some basic calculations but `pgfmath` could also be used.
The code uses two nested `foreach` to loop over all the cells.
On each cell at `(\x,\y)` an inner `foreach` loops over all possible horses jumps `(\px,\py)`. If the jump is outside the chessboard it is not counted.
The number of valid moves is accumulated in `\n` (remember to assign to it using `\global` or the value would be lost outside the body of the loop).
Then we draw the edges (on the background to avoid edges going over nodes drawn later); I avoid drawing the same line twice by just drawing the "forward" jumps.
The fill color is obtained by just multiplying the number of jumps by 10 to obtain a sensible percentage to blend `blue` with.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcount\n
\newcount\px
\newcount\py
\newcount\ncolor
\foreach \x in {1,...,8}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,8}{
        \n=0
        \foreach \dx/\dy in {-2/-1,-1/-2,1/-2,2/-1,2/1,1/2,-1/2,-2/1}{
            \px=\x
            \py=\y
            \advance\px by \dx\relax
            \advance\py by \dy\relax
            \ifnum\px>0
            \ifnum\px<9
            \ifnum\py>0
            \ifnum\py<9
                \global\advance\n by 1\relax
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                    \ifnum\dx=2
                        \draw (\x,\y) -- (\px,\py);
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\dy=2
                        \draw (\x,\y) -- (\px,\py);
                    \fi
                \end{pgfonlayer}
            \fi\fi\fi\fi
        }
        \ncolor=\n
        \multiply\ncolor by 10
        \node[draw,circle,fill={blue!\the\ncolor}] at (\x,\y) {\the\n};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image: preview]

A trick to avoid the `\ncolor` counter, if you are happy with the 10 factor for the color:

```
\node[draw,circle,fill={blue!\the\n0}] at (\x,\y) {\the\n};
```